# How to make the iMac go to sleep after certain amount of time?

Tags: imac, sleep-wake, energy

My MacBook Pro has settings for putting the Mac to sleep after a certain amount of idle time. My iMac does not have that setting. See the screenshot (sorry, it's in German).

I want to make sure that the iMac uses the least amount of energy when not used.

[image: Energy settings for an iMac]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sleep settings have changed due to the new Haswell chips. Because wake-up from sleep is so quick now, and because of the new automatic sleep modes in the CPU, the only thing drawing significant power is the display. Therefore, Apple deemed a sleep setting was only necessary for the display.

Click that last [Power Nap](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5394) checkbox if you want the computer to periodically wake up to do updates and check for mail, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try unticking "Automatisches Aktivieren des Computerruhezustandes bei ausgeschaltetem Display außer Kraft setzen"?

Then there should be another Slider which allows you to set the automatic Sleep.

Comment: Nope, that slider does not appear. I deactivated this setting, because I need to run some non PowerNap apps. But I would also like to still have the Mac sleep after some hours of idling.